# How can I make an NSTimer that repeats a specific number of times?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I want to call a function 50 times every .5 seconds using an NSTimer, but my only options are to have the timer run indefinitely or to create timers that are not repeating.  Can I get away with using timers to do what I want, or should I try using something else?

Comment: Add a counter, invalidate timer after 50 calls ... ?

Comment: There's no step three! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the number of function call using a class variable.

Once the max number of function call is met, you stop setting the next timer.

Using an iOS UIViewController class as an example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer:NSTimer? = nil;
    var times:Int = 0;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        startTimer()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func startTimer() {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, 
                                                 target: self, 
                                                 selector: "onTick:", 
                                                 userInfo: nil,
                                                 repeats: false)

    }

    func onTick(timer:NSTimer){
        println("Fired \(self.times)")
        times += 1
        // call your function
        if times < 50 {  // set the next timer 
             self.startTimer()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be `timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5,target: self, selector: "onTick:",userInfo: nil,repeats: false)`

Comment: Thanks this helps! What does "+=" means though?

Comment: It means `times = times + 1` here. You can check the Swift documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID69

Comment: I know this is an old question, but there's a repeat parameter for this purpose

var n: Int = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
n += 1
if n == 50 {
                timer.invalidate()
}

Answer (score 0):

You can make a timer in a function with recursive selector and a condition (timeoutCounter < 50):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timoutCounter:Int = 0
    let kTimeoutWaitingTime = 50

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        timeout()
    }

    func timeout() {

        if timoutCounter < kTimeoutWaitingTime {

            timoutCounter += 1    
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timeout), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        }
    }
}
```